# ViewPager implemented in a GridView. Gives ClickListener error and crashes

Tags: android

I am working on an application that have to have a `GridView` in the main activity containing images.

When an image is clicked, it has to open in another `Activity` in a bigger size. In this `Activity`, a `ViewPager` has to be implemented so that I can swipe right and left to change between the images.

I did already a huge part of the work and I don't know where the problem is but when i click on the image, the application crashes. Can anyone help me please ?

This is my main activity code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivityPager extends ActionBarActivity
{
    static int[] FLAG;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    GridView gridview;
    int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_pager);

         FLAG = new int[] { R.drawable.flag_of_argentina, R.drawable.flag_of_brazil,
                    R.drawable.flag_of_england, R.drawable.flag_of_france,
                    R.drawable.flag_of_germany, R.drawable.flag_of_italy, R.drawable.flag_of_spain,
                    R.drawable.flag_of_uruguay };

         AdapterGrid adapter = new AdapterGrid(MainActivityPager.this, FLAG);
         gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
         gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

         gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                count = gridview.getCount();
                intent.putExtra("count", count);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my AdapterGrid class code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AdapterGrid extends BaseAdapter
{
    private int[] mFlag;
    private Context mContext;

    public AdapterGrid(Context context, int[] flag) {
        //super(context, flag);
        mContext = context;
        mFlag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFlag.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(mFlag[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

This is my ActivityImage code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ActivityImage extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static int COUNT;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_image);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        COUNT = intent.getExtras().getInt("count");
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           return FragmentImage.init(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_image, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my FragmentImage class code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FragmentImage extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;

    static FragmentImage init(int pos) {
        FragmentImage frag = new FragmentImage();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", pos);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container,
                false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageResource(MainActivityPager.FLAG[fragVal]);

        return layoutView;
    }
}
```

These are my logcat errors :

```
07-22 09:40:29.915: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(25934): Parent view is not a TextView
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934): Process: com.example.gridviewpager, PID: 25934
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gridviewpager/com.example.gridviewpager.ActivityImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at com.example.gridviewpager.ActivityImage.onCreate(ActivityImage.java:27)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
07-22 09:40:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(25934):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where are you exactly getting the Exception? Please highlight your ActivityImage.java, line 27

Comment: the line 27 is the "mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `mPager` is `null`. Check if it actually has the id `pager` in your `activity_activity_image.xml` layout.

Comment: one more question .. when i click on my gridview .. how the viewpager is supposed to know the position of this image ?

Comment: You have to register some kind of click listener to your GridView that should give you the position or itemId of the clicked image. Pass that information to your ActivityImage via an Extra in the Intent you use to start the activity (see @Kamlesh Delat's answer for that bit). In the ActivityImage you can read that Extra in onResume() - via getIntent().getExtra(...)

Answer (score 0):

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, ActivityImage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", position);
                    count = gridview.getCount();
                    intent.putExtra("count", count);
                    startActivity(intent);


public Object getItem(int position) {
        return FLAG[posotion];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (long)position;
    }
```

Comment: i changed "view.getContext" to "getApplicationContext" and the activity is already added in the android manifest file.. nothing changed

Comment: please remove this line and try  grid = new View(mContext);

Comment: i tried it .. when i click on the image the new activity opens but its blank.

Comment: because your fragment adapted has no data

Comment: one more question .. when i click on my gridview .. how the viewpager is supposed to know the position of this image ?